# Android parallel updating the edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

In my activity I have three `EditText` fields, when ever I enter value into the any of the `EditText` the other two `EditText` fields to be updated, suppose in `EditText` A I entered value 4, the `EditText` B should have its decimal value and `EditText` C should have its binary value. I am trying to use the text watcher but it is somehow not working, can someone point me I right direction how can I parallel update the `EditText`.

```
edditvalue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        hexToBin(qtyString);

    }
});
```

**Methods:**

```
public double hextodecimal(String s){
    double r = 0;

        if(s.equals("a") || s.equals("b") || s.equals("c") ||
                s.equals("d") || s.equals("e") ||s.equals("f") )
        {   
             r = Integer.parseInt(s, 16 );
            r= (double)  r;
        }
        else
        {
            r = Integer.parseInt(s, 16 );
        }

    return r;
}

public static String hexToBin(String s) {
    String k = new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
    return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}
```

Comment: You will have to elaborate on "somehow not working"... ;)

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but in your "afterTextChanged", you have to set the text of the editText. like,  "editText1.setText(DECIMAL)" and "editText2.setText(BINARY)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and just added `setText` calls. Its printing values in EditTexts properly.

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        //you would need to handle your code in this manner so app doesn't crash if user hits backspace and removes all entered characters
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
            editText2.setText(hexToBin(qtyString));
            editText3.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
        }
        else {
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

P.S: Make sure to use `inputType` properly, else your app will crash if user enters character in editText1

Comment: hi when i am entering like 1 then 2 i edit text it should take as 12 but it is taking as 18, what to do

Comment: When i am entering in the edit text like 123 its decimal should be 123.0 but the result is giving as 291.0, this afterTextChanged method will take it as 123? or maybe my hextodecimal methos is wrong?

Comment: Method is wrong. Because, text is always taken from edittext properly. If you still want to confirm, debug or put this: `System.out.println("value: "+qtyString);` before passing data to function and you will see it's correct :) @teekib

Answer (score 0):

### **Little change in code...**

```
  edditvalue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
                hexToBin(qtyString);

            }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });

        }
```

Comment: where should i update the other edittext fields? and when i amentering like 5 then 6 it should take as 56 but it is taking as 86

Comment: @teekib  pls try to print log in yr program.. Charsequence s always give appened text

and for two or more edittext refer MysticMagic code in your ontextchane method